# How to make leg movements, OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

When I try to make leg movements around a pivot point (top of leg), what happens instead is that the legs starts revolving around the wrong point, when I just want the legs to swing back and forth.

How do I fix this problem?

This is my code.

```
glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(x+0.0f, y+6.0f, z-1.5f);
    glRotatef(walk, 1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-6.0f, z-3.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-6.0f, z-0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-18.0f, z-0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-18.0f, z-3.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-6.0f, z-3.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-6.0f, z-0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-18.0f, z-0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-18.0f, z-3.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-6.0f, z-3.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-6.0f, z-3.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-18.0f, z-3.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-18.0f, z-3.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-6.0f, z-0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-6.0f, z-0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-18.0f, z-0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-18.0f, z-0.5f);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(x+0.0f, y+6.0f, z+1.5f);
    glRotatef(-walk, 0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-6.0f, z+3.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-6.0f, z+0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-18.0f, z+0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-18.0f, z+3.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-6.0f, z+3.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-6.0f, z+0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-18.0f, z+0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-18.0f, z+3.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-6.0f, z+3.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-6.0f, z+3.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-18.0f, z+3.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-18.0f, z+3.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-6.0f, z+0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-6.0f, z+0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y-18.0f, z+0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.5f); glVertex3f(x-1.0f, y-18.0f, z+0.5f);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: may try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ instead. A site specialized for these kind of questions.

Comment: Which point _should_ things be rotating around?

Comment: Please show us what is walk and how you define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All OpenGL rotations are done around the point (0, 0, 0). So if you want to rotate a vertex around specific point (rx, ry, rz), you have to do the following transformations:

```
Translate(-rx, -ry, -rz);
Rotate(alpha, beta, gamma);
Translate(rx, ry, rz);
```

Comment: The order of the two translate should be switched.

Comment: That depends. I've written the transformations in time order and in that terms they're correct (center of rotation has to be transformed into (0, 0, 0) point). If you apply transformations manually, you shall do them right in the sequence I've presented. However, if you apply transformations by matrices and you want to generate a transformation matrix, indeed the sequence has to be reverted (due to transformation combining properties).

Comment: Actually, I needed the translations to be switched. Otherwise, your answer has solved my problem.